# Removing "action" from a module's route. Is it possible?

Tags: craft3, routing, modules

I have a module with a route that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/actions/module/controller/action
```

Is it possible to set up a custom route within my module so I can send people to:

```
http://localhost/module/controller/action
```

I'm new to Craft 3, but so far loving it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can add the route in `config/routes.php`.

```pho
return [
    'custom/route' => 'module/controller/action',
];
```

(See https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules)

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. But it looks like it totally should work. I think it might be something screwy with my local development environment, so I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks for the quick answer! I'll mark it as accepted once I get my env issues figured out!